# drawRect: is not always called after setNeedsDisplay:YES when parent view is layer-backed

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

I have a basic Cocoa app with a custom `NSCollectionView` that overrides `drawRect:` to draw a red background (for illustration purposes).

I noticed that at seemingly random times, `drawRect:` would not be called although I invoked `setNeedsDisplay:YES`. Other times it worked and the collection view had a red background.

It took me a few hours, but then I finally noticed that high up in the view hierarchy one of the parent views was a **layer-backed view** (I had "Core Animation Layer" checked in Interface Builder to add a shadow to an element).

Changing that parent view to not use layer-backing immediately solved the problem and `drawRect:` is then always called as expected.

What puzzles me is that with layer-backing enabled on a parent view, `drawRect:` would be called sometimes, but not always.

Should I assume that I *can't reliably override* `drawRect:` in any subview if a parent view is layer-backed?

Comment: Edited to change "overwrite" to "override".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the WWDC 2012 video on layer-backed views, and read the documentation for `-layerContentsRedrawPolicy`.  Sounds like you want `NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay`.